# UWP Visual offset animation not working

Tags: c#, uwp, composition

For my app I want to be able to use the Composition API to animate the Offset of an UIElement
This element is predefined in Xaml and I have found that the Visual layer of these controls only get calculated **AFTER** an animation has been triggered...

This behavior results in the animation only showing when it has been called a second time

My Xaml

```xml
<StackPanel x:Name="ActionButtonsPanel" Margin="50,175,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button x:Name="CreateNewButton" Tag="&#xE160;" Content="Create New..." Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}" Click="CreateNewButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="OpenFileButton" Tag="&#xE838;" Content="Open File..." Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}" Margin="0,10,0,0" Click="OpenFileButton_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

My Code

```
private void ShowNextButtons(UIElement Item1, UIElement Item2) {
    var _compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;

    var visual1 = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(Item1);
    visual1.CenterPoint = new Vector3(0, (float) Item1.RenderSize.Height / 2F, 0);

    var animationGroup1 = _compositor.CreateAnimationGroup();

    var offset1 = visual1.Offset; //First Time: Offset = <0,0,0>

    var fadeOut = _compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
    fadeOut.Target = "Opacity";
    fadeOut.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
    fadeOut.InsertKeyFrame(0, 1);
    fadeOut.InsertKeyFrame(1, 0);
    //animationGroup1.Add(fadeOut); Not included: To be able to click a second time

    var slideOut = _compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
    slideOut.Target = "Offset.X";
    slideOut.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
    slideOut.InsertKeyFrame(0, offset1.X);
    slideOut.InsertKeyFrame(1, offset1.X - 20F);
    animationGroup1.Add(slideOut);

    visual1.StartAnimationGroup(animationGroup1);
}
```

The `Offset.X` animation is only visible the second time the method has been called

Comment: You need to show a full example of your code. We have no idea which element you are animating, and what triggers the animation.

Comment: I'm animating the Stackpanel, sorry for that :)

Comment: Try removing the margin on your `StackPanel` and see if that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely hitting the an issue with Composition & XAML position properties conflicting with each other. http://blog.robmikh.com/uwp/xaml/composition/2016/07/16/changes-to-xaml-composition-interop.html

Your simplest solution is to wrap whatever you're animating inside Borders and apply any layout properties to those borders (like Margins), and then your offset animations *should* now work on what you're animating (as the XAML layout engine should now have no reason to overwrite the Composition Offset property on the animation target with the relative XAML position)

Alternatively, if you're targeting the Creators Update you can animate the Composition Translation property instead. See: http://varunshandilya.com/offset-animation-gets-stomped-here-is-how-to-solve-it-in-uwp-creators-update/

Comment: I changed my project to target **only** the Creators Update, by changing it in the project properties. I can't use the solution in your last link though... What am I missing?

Comment: NVM, found it: The link says: `EnableTranslation` and it should be `SetIsTranslationEnabled`

Comment: Aaand the second link is broken.

Comment: The link is broken, but the following solution worked for me:

`ElementCompositionPreview::SetIsTranslationEnabled(YourElement, true);`
`YourElementVisual->StartAnimation("Translation", YourExpression);`